# How to implmement the Star shape in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Requirement : Star Shape should get added on click of a button .

I have implemented to add a circle by using the ng style in html, now i want to implement the star shape in similar way and for that i need to write a different class "star-six" in css.

But below html code already contains one css class "shapeClass". I have used the below jquery code in my controller method  and added the css class "star-six".

The problem i am facing is my new css class"star-six" is replacing the existing class "shapeClass" for all the div's.

can someone please tell how to implment the star shape using the below controller .

HTML:

```
 <div class="shapeClass" ng-repeat="element in viewModel.elementContainer.element"
                 data-ng-style="shapeCtrl.getShapeStyle($index)">

  </div>
```

Controller:

```
vm.getShapeStyle = function (index) {

            if ($scope.viewModel.elementContainer.element[index].name == "addCircle") {

                    return {
                    "width": "100px",
                    "height": "100px",
                    "background": "red",
                    "-moz-border-radius": "50px",
                    "-webkit-border-radius": "50px",
                    "border-radius": "50px"

                };

            }

            if ($scope.viewModel.elementContainer.element[index].name == "addStar") {
                $('.shapeClass').hasClass('star-six')
                if ($('.star-six').hasClass('shapeClass')) {
                    $('.star-six').removeClass('shapeClass');
                }
                return {


                };

            }
```

CSS:

```
.shapeClass {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
 position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-six {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
.star-six:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 30px;
    left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Can please share JSFiddle link of your code?

Comment: $('.star-six').removeClass('shapeClass'); you are removing it yourself.

Comment: Yes, But how do we add star-six class only for that div when the condition $scope.viewModel.elementContainer.element[index].name == "addStar" is satisfied